# Why is my custom ListView not showing all the widgets?

Tags: android, listview

I am writing an appointments application with a customised Listview. The ListView consists of a

- View, whose colour indicates priority
- Checkbox, to select the item with.
- DateText, to show what date the appointment is
- MonthText, to show what month the appointment is
- TimeText, to show when the appointment is
- Title, which stores the summary of the appointment

Each row in the listView should look something like this:

[image]

But only two widgets are visible: DateText and MonthText. The rest are not. Why is this the case?

[image]

My `XML` and `getView()` method are below:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <View
        android:id="@+id/priorityView"
        android:layout_width="20dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#cccccc"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/selectedCheckbox"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@id/priorityView"
        android:layout_alignTop="@id/priorityView"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/priorityView"
        android:gravity="center">
    </CheckBox>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/dateText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@id/priorityView"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/selectedCheckbox"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:paddingBottom="2dip"
        android:paddingLeft="5dip"
        android:paddingRight="5dip"
        android:paddingTop="2dip"
        android:text="@string/empty"
        android:textSize="20dip"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/monthText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@id/monthText"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@id/dateText"
        android:layout_alignRight="@id/dateText"
        android:layout_below="@id/dateText"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="5dip"
        android:text="@string/empty"
        android:textSize="10dip" >
    </TextView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/timeText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@id/priorityView"
        android:layout_alignTop="@id/priorityView"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/dateText"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="5dip"
        android:text="@string/empty" >
    </TextView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/titleText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@id/priorityView"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@id/priorityView"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/timeText"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="5dip"
        android:text="@string/empty" >
    </TextView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

getView()

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

                    // List views that go off the screen are recycled.

                    View recycledView = convertView;

                    if (recycledView == null) {
                        /*
                         * If there is no view to recycle (e.g. when the listview is
                         * first created) we must inflate the view from the xml file
                         * using Layout Inflater.
                         */

                        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

                        recycledView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, null);
                    }

                    /*
                     * We now have a view to work with. We will now fill in the contents
                     * of this list view item.
                     */

                    Appointment current = items.get(position);
                    if (current != null) {

                        Log.e("crap",current.toString());

                        View priorityIndicator = (View) recycledView.findViewById(R.id.priorityView);
                        CheckBox selectedCheckbox = (CheckBox) recycledView.findViewById(R.id.selectedCheckbox);
                        TextView dateText = (TextView) recycledView.findViewById(R.id.dateText);
                        TextView monthText = (TextView) recycledView.findViewById(R.id.monthText);
                        TextView timeText = (TextView) recycledView.findViewById(R.id.timeText);
                        TextView titleText = (TextView) recycledView.findViewById(R.id.titleText);

                        //Set priority indictor to appropriate colour.
                        selectedCheckbox.setChecked(true);

                        switch (current.getPriority()) {
                        case PRIORITY_LOW:
                            priorityIndicator.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
                            break;

                        case PRIORITY_NORMAL:
                            priorityIndicator.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
                            break;

                        case PRIORITY_HIGH:
                            priorityIndicator.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
                            break;

                        default:
                            priorityIndicator.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
                            break;
                        }

                        //Leave the selected checkbox alone.

                        //Set dateText to show the date of the appointment
                        dateText.setText("29");
                        monthText.setText("SEP");
                        timeText.setText("11:00");
                        titleText.setText(current.getTitle());
                    }

                    return recycledView;
                }
```

Comment: I was just reviewing the code. The reason only two widgets are visible and the rest are not is because that these are the only two widgets that have data in them. The rest are empty. Just thought I'd mention in case someone else makes such an absent-minded mistake :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using Linear Layout with gravity attribute instead of relative layout. Relative layout is not ideal for inflating in a listview.

Comment: what is there in the priority view?

Comment: Nothing. The priority uses a colour to represent the priority.  It works if I use an empty TextView instead of a View.

Comment: use dp instead of dip and check.