# Android match_parent not changing height when I adding Views to LinearLayout

Tags: android, android-layout

I have `ListView` with items which may contain different line counts (few key:value fields). So I've put `LinearLayout` and adding lines inside adapter's `getView`

Now I want to draw an arrow `>` at the right side of list item centered vertically.

Here's my layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    style="@style/ListItemContainerBase"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?activatableItemBackground"
    android:baselineAligned="true"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/list_item_middle_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
    </LinearLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/arrow_container"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:background="#bbbbbb" >

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:padding="8dip"
            android:src="@drawable/arrow" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Now my problem is:
arrow_container not resizing after adding views to list_item_middle_container.
It wraps ImageView only but not fills parent height.
I've tried to call requestLayout and switch visibility on/off but no results.
Thanks!

Comment: Here is my answer to a similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12672711/why-is-my-custom-listview-not-showing-all-the-widgets/12672885#12672885